# ASP.NET MVC - How to show partial views with arraylist data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I want to display three different partial views on a aspx webpage based on the buttons selected. That part is working fine. But then each of the partial views would read separate sections from the xml file and would provide data the view as well. I have tried to pass the data as Arraylist to the view but the partial view does not show up now. Without passing the data, the partial views were working. **Please note I am using aspx instead of razor.** Any ideas as to how to make this work so that upon clicking any of the 3 buttons, a different partial view is displayed with the xml data as well. Thanks in advance.

RenderVOIP.aspx

```
$(function() {
        $('#InfoButton').on("click", function() {        
            $.get('<%= Url.Action("InfoAction", "HardwareRequisition")%>', function (data) {
                $( "#myContentView" ).html( data );
            });
            $('#NotesButton').on("click", function() {              
                $.get('<%= Url.Action("NotesAction", "HardwareRequisition")%>', function (data) {
                    $( "#myContentView" ).html( data );
                });
                $('#OrdersButton').on("click", function() {                  
                    $.get('<%= Url.Action("OrdersAction", "HardwareRequisition")%>', function (data) {
                        $( "#myContentView" ).html( data );
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });

<input type="text" id="box" style="width: 100px;" />
      <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12" id="account-subnavigation">
                        <div class="btn-group" style=" margin-bottom:10px; margin-left:10px;">                         
                            <button class="btn btn-info" style="width:120px" id="InfoButton">Info</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-info" style="width:120px" id="NotesButton">Notes</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-info" style="width:120px" id="ordersButton">Orders</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

               <div class="row" id="myContentView">

                </div>
```

voipSubform1.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Products>" %>

<h2>VoIP Subform 1</h2>
 test
<fieldset id="voipdetails" class="section2">

    <table class="table table-bordered"> 
<tr> 
<th>Id</th> 
<th>Product Name</th> 
<th>Product Cost</th> 
</tr> 
<% foreach (var product in ((IEnumerable<Products>)ViewData["data"]))

{ %> 
<tr> 
<td> 
    <%: product.ProductId%>
</td> 
<td> 
<%= product.ProductName%>
</td> 
<td> 
<%= product.ProductCost%>
</td> 
</tr> 
<% } %>
</table>
 
HardwareRequisitionController.cs

public ActionResult InfoAction()
            {
                //return View("VoIPSubform1", _repository.GetForm(8));
      //          return PartialView("_MySecondPartialView");
      //          return View("RenderVOIPForm", _repository.GetForm(8));

                var filename = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "App_Data\\" + "log\\" + "logErrors.txt";
                try
                {
                    XMLReader readXML = new XMLReader();
                    var data = readXML.ReturnListOfProducts().ToList();

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename, true);
                    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + e.Message + " " + e.InnerException);
                    sw.Close();
                }
               // return View(data.ToList());
                XMLReader readXML2 = new XMLReader();
                var data2 = readXML2.ReturnListOfProducts();

                var sw2 = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename, true);
                sw2.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + data2);
                sw2.Close();

                return PartialView("_VoIPSubform1", data2);

           //     return View("_VoIPSubform1", data.ToList());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested in the solution, I added these lines inside the controller and it worked.

```
ViewData["data"] = data2;
return PartialView("_VoIPSubform1");
```